# Android keystore not setting validity no matter how big I set it

Tags: android, certificate, keystore, android-keystore

I'm getting really frustrated here. I keep creating new keystores because every time I create one and I check it out, the validity is ALWAYS being set for only 4 months. I don't understand.. I'm setting the validity, but it's not working! Anyone ever encounter this or have any idea's what to do??

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\test.keystore -alias test -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

keytool works well. I think you're not checking correctly the validity of the certificate. For example with

keytool -list -v -keystore c: \ temp \ test.jks

This is your example executed with JDK 1.8.0_31  (I only changed the name of the keystore from `c:\test.keystore` to `c:\temp\test.jks`)

[image: keytool example]